# storing of decimal part in Embedded c and use of that

Tags: c

I am working on Embedded C and  in that I want to divide 250/1024 and I want to store result completely including  decimal part. later I want to multiply this with adc result then need to display the final result ??? Please anyone help me on this..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
float r = 250.0/1024;

printf("%f\n", r * adc);
```

Comment: This is fine, assuming that the OP's microprocessor has floating point instructions or enough memory for a FP library. Since he's asking, I'd assume not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only `int` math (and adc >= 0):

```
int numerator = 250;
int denominator = 1024;
int product = (adc * numerator + denominator/2)/denominator;
```

`denominator/2` is for rounding.